# Fluent Assertions: Approximately compare a classes properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have a class `Vector3D` that has the properties `X`, `Y` and `Z` of type double (it also has other properties such as `Magnitude`).

What is the best way of approximately comparing all the properties or a selection of the properties at a given precision using Fluent Assertions?

Currently I have been doing it like this:

```
calculated.X.Should().BeApproximately(expected.X, precision);
calculated.Y.Should().BeApproximately(expected.Y, precision);
calculated.Z.Should().BeApproximately(expected.Z, precision);
```

Is there a single line approach that will achieve the same thing? Such as using `ShouldBeEquivalentTo`, or does this require constructing a generic extension method that allows properties to be included / excluded?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes it's possible using [ShouldBeEquivalentTo](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#equivalency-comparison-behavior). The following code will check all properties that are of type double with a precision of 0.1 :

```cs
double precision = 0.1;
calculated.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options
    .Using<double>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeApproximately(ctx.Expectation, precision))
    .WhenTypeIs<double>());
```

If you want to compare only the X, Y and Z properties change the When constraint like this :

```
double precision = 0.1;
calculated.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(b, options => options
    .Using<double>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeApproximately(ctx.Expectation, precision))
    .When(info => info.SelectedMemberPath == "X" ||
                  info.SelectedMemberPath == "Y" ||
                  info.SelectedMemberPath == "Z"));
```

Another approach is to explicitly tell to FluentAssertions which properties should be compared, but it's a bit less elegant :

```
double precision = 0.1;
calculated.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(b, options => options
    .Including(info => info.SelectedMemberPath == "X" ||
                       info.SelectedMemberPath == "Y" ||
                       info.SelectedMemberPath == "Z")
    .Using<double>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeApproximately(ctx.Expectation, precision))
    .When(info => true));
```

Since the `Using` statement does not return a `EquivalencyAssertionOptions<T>` we need to hack it by calling the `When` statement with an always true expression.

Comment: That's neat. So `.When` has to be used in this particular case instead of `.Including` to specify which properties are used for the equivalence test?

Comment: Including is to explicitly tell to FluentAssertions wich properties to use during the comparison. I have updated my answer with an explaination.

Comment: I'm guess it is a matter of preference, but is there any disadvantage to using `.Including(info => info.X).Including(info => info.Y).Including(info => info.Z)` over the `info.SelectedMemberPath == "X"...`?

Comment: The overload you point allow you to check at compile time the correctness of your expression, but it is a bit more verbose.

Comment: Very helpful answer! Is there a solution if double is also nullable?