# Fluent Assertions: Approximately compare the properties of objects stored in Lists

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

This question builds on one I previously asked:

[Fluent Assertions: Approximately compare a classes properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782975/fluent-assertions-approximately-compare-a-classes-properties)

If I have a class, say Vector3

```cs
public class Vector3
{
    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }
    public double Z { get; }

    public Vector3(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }
}
```

and it is formed into two lists, how can I approximately compare the properties of the `Vector3` objects in the two lists to see if they are the same. This is what I have so far (I'm using the xUnit framework, but that shouldn't make any difference):

```cs
public double precision = 1e-5;

[Fact]
public void ApproximatelyCompareVector3List()
{
    // Arrange
    var expectedList = new List<Vector3>
    {
        new Vector3(0.5, 1, 3),
        new Vector3(0, 2, 4)
    };

    // Act
    var calculatedList = List<Vector3>
    {
        new Vector3(0.4999999, 1.0000001, 3),
        new Vector3(0.0000001, 2.0000001, 4)
    };

    //Assert
    calculatedList.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedList, options => options
        .Using<double>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeApproximately(ctx.Expectation, precision))
        .When(info => info.SelectedMemberPath == "X" ||
                      info.SelectedMemberPath == "Y" ||
                      info.SelectedMemberPath == "Z" ));
}
```

However, this seems to skip the approximately test and require exact ordering. Is it possible to have either exact ordering or any ordering for approximately comparing the properties of objects contained in a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it is a bit old question, but anyway if someone stumbles upon the same problem:
The code inside `Using<double>` is not executed because selected member path comparison is wrong. You're comparing lists, that's why the path will look like something like `[0].X`

So you can fix it with:

```
.When(info => info.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("X") ||
                  info.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Y") ||
                  info.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Z")));
```

Or just:

```
.WhenTypeIs<double>());
```

Exact ordering is not required in `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` by default.

**UPDATE**: `SelectedMemeberPath` was renamed to `Path` [in v.6.0.0.](https://fluentassertions.com/releases/#600)

Comment: That works when all properties are included, though is it possible to modify the `When` so that only selected properties are compared. For example if I only want to approximately compare `X` and `Z` and not `Y` from the two lists.

Comment: Ok, so use `.When(info => info.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("X") || info.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Z"));`

Comment: I tried that, but the test fails with: _Expected item[0].Y to be 1, but found 1.0000001. Expected item[1].Y to be 2, but found 2.0000001. Expected item[2].Y to be 0, but found -1E-07._ So it doesn't appears to be ignoring `Y`, and it is still checking it without using approximately.

Comment: With `When` you're defining which members to compare approximately. If you want `Y` to be compared approximately it should be included into expression `.When(info => info.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Y"));`

Comment: I think I got it, I have to specifically include the properties I want, or exclude the properties that I don't; using the `Including` and `Excluding` extensions. Otherwise all properties are automatically included.

Comment: @Ayb4btu, yes but this is not related to `BeApproximately` comparison

Comment: You're right, I went off on a bit of a tangent. Thanks for the answer.